# pass svn revision number to cruise control api from C#

Tags: c#, svn, cruisecontrol.net

I want to pass different svn revision numbers to cruisecontrol, so that it can create different builds for all provided revision numbers. I tried using cruise control API to do force build

```
const string ipAddressOrHostNameOfCcServer = "localhost";
using (var client = new CruiseServerHttpClient(
    string.Format("http://{0}/ccnet/", ipAddressOrHostNameOfCcServer))) 
{

    var request = new IntegrationRequest(
        BuildCondition.ForceBuild, LocalPath, "dipakm");

    request.BuildValues.Add("VersionToBuild", "167");
    client.Request("MyFirstProject", request);        
}
```

but the parameters is not available in ccnet.config

```
<cb:scope ProjectName="MyFirstProject">
<project name="$(ProjectName)"
       description="demoproject showing a small config">
<parameters>
    <textParameter name="VersionToBuild">
        <display>SVN Version to Build</display>
        <description>Which SVN version to Build?</description>
        <default>HEAD</default>           
        <required>true</required>
    </textParameter>
</parameters>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you should be able to use [parameters](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Parameters) to pass svn revision to Cruise Contol .NET's tasks and do what you need with it.

Comment: Thanks @sinnerinc. I saw that option, my problem is I want to generate build for every revision which is higher than the one on my local machine. Also using API I can pass single parameter but not sure how can I pass list of revisions which should be looped in ccnet.config